# BigQuery UNION ALL Tables with Mismatched Column Types

Tags: google-bigquery

How do you change a column type to date when all the values are set to NULL? I need to UNION ALL the two tables below. To make table 2 match table 1 I had to add a column using NULL as date. I tried to use CAST(NULL as DATE) as date but I received the following BQ error "Parameterized types are not allowed in CAST expressions.". My SQL is below, does anyone have any ideas of how to approach this union knowing the final output can't use a fake date for the rows in table2.date?

**TABLE 1**
[image]

**Table 2**[image]

```
SELECT date,value,dimension FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(NULL as DATE) as date,value,dimension FROM table2
```

Comment: your script works for me as it is in your question! also, please do not use images to present your data - rather use text so we can play with it!

Comment: Tried your script and no error is encountered as well. Can you confirm if you are running the script on the correct tables?

Comment: Thank you both for the quick responses. This is only part of my larger query and you are both right. I think something else is causing the issue. Thank you both for the help is eliminating this as the issue.